# BigQuery web interface not presenting errors for legacy SQL query

Tags: google-bigquery

I running the simple following query from BigQuery web interface. Instead of returning an error, the query runs indefinitely.

`select 
  word 
from [bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare] 
where clkjsdf is not null`

I'm using chrome version Version 62.0.3202.94 on Mac (Sierra). 
When running the same query in standard SQL I do get the appropriate error.

Is there a way to avoid this annoying issue (different browser, clear cookies, other)?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. I get `Field 'clkjsdf' not found in table 'bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare'.` If you have a job ID for one of the queries that appears to run indefinitely, you could file a bug on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B).

Comment: On a related note, if you'd like to try out the new BigQuery UI that is in development (which defaults to standard SQL), you can [submit the request form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf6hyfvoWZ8eUbbKWq9fzVfj7ljVyl2SdhtWH038Xrx2eHVrw/viewform).

Comment: Same as Elliot. I get `Error: Field 'clkjsdf' not found in table 'bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare'.`